# How to send byte numbers as is, instead of sending them as individual digits in Android Bluetooth outputStream?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth

I want to send, for ex: 239 as 239 over my Bluetooth outputStream but currently, my Bluetooth code sends this as "2", then "3" and then "9"; 3 bytes in total instead of 1 byte and receiving is also happening in 3 bytes.

**Code on the Tx side (Java)**:
Sending data every 10 seconds using a timer.

Packaging data as:

```
    private void startTimer() {
        TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] mByte = new byte[1];

                mTimeStamp += mPeriod;  //mPeriod = 10000; initial mTimeStamp = 0
                mData += 2; //initial mData = 0

                String s = "239";
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mTimeStamp & 0xFF000000) >> 24));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mTimeStamp & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mTimeStamp & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mTimeStamp & 0x000000FF) >> 0));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = "0";
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = "0";
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mData & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
                s = Integer.toString(((mData & 0x000000FF) >> 0));
                mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(mByte);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("schedule", true);

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 10, mPeriod);
    }
```

And the write function:

```
//Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "write: bytes length: " + bytes.length);
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

Log cat output for the same:

```
01-06 23:33:32.012 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 239
01-06 23:33:32.012 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 3
01-06 23:33:32.018 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.018 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 0
01-06 23:33:32.018 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 1
01-06 23:33:32.020 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.020 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 4
01-06 23:33:32.020 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 1
01-06 23:33:32.021 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.021 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 147
01-06 23:33:32.021 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 3
01-06 23:33:32.022 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.022 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 224
01-06 23:33:32.022 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 3
01-06 23:33:32.024 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.024 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 0
01-06 23:33:32.024 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 1
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 0
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 1
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 0
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 1
01-06 23:33:32.033 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
01-06 23:33:32.034 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: 60
01-06 23:33:32.034 19455-19682/com.example.user.bluetooth_communication D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: bytes length: 2
```

**Code on the Rx side (Kotlin):**

```
// Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            Log.d("ConnectionActivity", "Inside ListeningThread")
            while (true) { // Read from the InputStream
                if(mBluetoothSocket != null)
                {
                    try {
                        bytes = mBluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(buffer)
                        val incomingMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                        Log.d("ConnectionActivity", "No of bytes: $bytes, " + "InputStream: $incomingMessage")
                        var intentIncomingMessage = Intent("incomingMessage")
                        intentIncomingMessage.putExtra("theMessage", incomingMessage)
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intentIncomingMessage)

                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.message)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
```

Sample logcat output:

```
2020-01-12 16:12:10.817 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 3, InputStream: 239
2020-01-12 16:12:10.848 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 12, InputStream: 074324000094
2020-01-12 16:12:20.817 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 3, InputStream: 239
2020-01-12 16:12:20.842 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 10, InputStream: 0783000096
2020-01-12 16:12:30.817 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 3, InputStream: 239
2020-01-12 16:12:30.845 13707-13937 D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 12, InputStream: 071221600098
```

In the above output, what I need is: 1st two lines data should have been as

```
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 239
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 0
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 74
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 32
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 40
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 0
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 0
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 0
D/ConnectionActivity: No of bytes: 1, InputStream: 94
```

I think this issue partly, if not fully, has to do with how I am transmitting data. In the Tx side logcat output, one can see, the byte length for 239 is being printed as 3 instead of 1.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you want to transmit a number(possible as large as `Long.MAX_VALUE`) as a byte array, but as it stands you are converting the number to a string, and then the string to a byte array?

Comment: What do you think `mByte = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` does?

Comment: It converts a string to a byte array using the UTF_8 encoding.

Comment: @PiRocks: I want to transmit, for ex: {239, 0, 0, 25, 20, 0, 0, 0, 115} as bytes. However, 239 must be a single byte just like 0. The reception should happen as a single byte too.

Comment: So you mean unsigned bytes?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: I know I am making a mistake by getting them as "digit bytes". But I hope, what I want to achieve is clear both on the Tx and Rx side.

Comment: To clarify allmost all types in java are signed, which means that bytes are from -128 to 127. You can of course use some arithmetic to work around this

Comment: @PiRocks: Yes, I need the bytes to be "unsigned". On the Rx side, I am using Kotlin which does has "UByte" data type. I am new to both the languages, not sure how to achieve what I want to...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205826/discussion-between-pirocks-and-naresh).

Comment: If you want to send bytes why are you starting  with `Strings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some java stream basics:

```
final byte number1 = 89;
final byte number2 = 45;
final byte number3 = 75;
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(byteOutput);
o.writeByte(number1);
o.writeByte(number2);
o.writeByte(number3);
//for other types you can do:
//        o.writeBoolean();
//        o.writeUTF();
//etc.
final byte[] bytes = byteOutput.toByteArray();
o.close();
//now you can send this array.
// to read the data sent simply take your input stream:
// or alternatively: val inputStream = DataInputStream(mBluetoothSocket!!.inputStream)
final ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
final DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(byteInputStream);
System.out.println(inputStream.readByte()); //prints number 1 aka 89
System.out.println(inputStream.readByte()); //prints number 2 aka 45
System.out.println(inputStream.readByte()); //prints number 3 aka 75
```

This should allow you to send raw bytes without converting to and from strings.

In Kotlin, you can add `.toUByte()` to `inputStream.readByte()` if unsigned bytes are desired.